# Securing access to a database accessed from a mobile device

Tags: database, security, mobile

I want to write a mobile application to access a database that is currently held on our LAN and accessed by an application on the network. I know that I can open a port in our firewall to redirect the traffic from the mobile device to the database but I a concerned about the security.

What ways could I consider to provide secure mobile access to the database while still allowing access from the local network application?

Comment: What about a SOAP service or writing a web-based system and getting the data using JSON? At least then you could use some logic to check credentials.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I would do in this situation is provide an interface like WCF (REST/JSON/etc.) to the database for your mobile users.  Eventually you could even convert over to using that for the LAN and the web.  The result would be even better security all around.

Here are some examples of how to do this:

Java RESTful Web Services Guide - http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/javase/index-137171.html

WCF Guide - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/netframework/dd939784

Overview of SOAP - http://www.w3schools.com/soap/default.asp

Comment: Thanks @biggsTRC and @Jared. A couple of further questions. Could you point me to any web resources that would give me a heads-up on such an interface or do you know of an existing interface that is compatible with Firebird? Thanks

Comment: @williamsdb - It all depends on what language you are currently using (Java, C#, etc.)  However, I've included basic information about how to create the different types in my post.  As for FirebirdSQL, if you are already accessing it with a programming language for your LAN application, you would do so the same way.  These above services are simply applications that run on a server and are formatted a bit differently.  Your DAL (Data Access Layer) should work the same for your service as it does for your LAN application.

Answer (score 0):

As Firebird provides a number of connectivity options (JDBC, .Net, Python) you have a lot of choice/flexibility about how you deploy your web service interface.  I would look into AXIS if you are thinking of deploying with Java (http://axis.apache.org/axis/) or WCF if .Net (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd203052.aspx) Whether you go for a RESTful or SOAP/XML-RPC interface depends largely on what functionality to you want to expose and to whom.  A public API that you want to make available to a broad audience would probably work best as a RESTful interface (think, Twitter, Flickr etc.) if it was a closed/proprietary interface you would probably go down the SOAP route.  However, mobile app development frameworks are broadly better at consuming RESTful web services than SOAP in my experience. With native iPhone apps I believe you have to roll your own SOAP interface.  Some of the app accelerator tools have both SOAP and REST client support.